# bash script simple array

Tags: arrays, bash

I have 2 files:
/tmp/first.txt  and
/tmp/last.txt

```
cat /tmp/first.txt
john
adam
max

cat /tmp/last.txt
smith
moore
caviar
```

I want to combine the contents of these two files, something (output) like this:

```
john smith
adam moore
max caviar
```

what i've already did:

```
first=()
getfirst() {
    i=0
    while read line # Read a line
    do
        array[i]=$line # Put it into the array
        i=$(($i + 1))
    done < $1
}
getfirst "/tmp/first.txt"
for a in "${array[@]}"
do
        echo "$a"
done

last=()
getlast() {
    i=0
    while read line # Read a line
    do
        array[i]=$line # Put it into the array
        i=$(($i + 1))
    done < $1
}
getlast "/tmp/first.txt"
for b in "${array[@]}"
do
        echo "$b"
done
```

I've done some look alike (using iteration):

```
for x in {1..2}
do
echo $a[$x] $b[$x];
done
```

but the output is only:

```
max caviar
```

Comment: You create the `first` and `last` arrays, but never use them. Then you access arrays `a` and `b`, but these weren't declared as arrays, they're just the iteration variables in the two `for` loops.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simpler solution is using `paste`:

```
$ paste -d ' ' first.txt last.txt
john smith
adam moore
max caviar
```

If you don't have `paste`, then using arrays:

```
$ first=($(cat first.txt))
$ last=($(cat last.txt))
$ for ((i = 0; i < 3; ++i)); do echo ${first[$i]} ${last[$i]}; done
john smith
adam moore
max caviar
```